# Find out Kafka version remotely

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to find out the Kafka version from outside the cluster?
(maybe with `telnet` or another tool)

just for clarification, I don't have ssh neither to Kafka nor zookeeper.

Comment: You have telnet, but not SSH access? :( Do you have access to JMX? But as long as it is greater than 0.10, why do you need this? If you have a non matching API client, it'll perform API Version negotiations internally

Comment: Why you want that? One Way If you  want to know only version login to kafka manager/ui..

Comment: I want to know which specific version to use on my consumer/producer.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution to retrieve the version of kafka Cluster is to used the JMX metrics exposed by each broker. Usually, JMX is activate on brokers for monitoring purpose.

The version can is exposed by ach broker through the metric name :

```
kafka.server:type=app-info,version=<([-.\w]+)>
```

For doing this, you can use *[jconsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)* or the [JmxTool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools) available in the Apache/Confluent Kafka distribution.

Here is an example :

```
$> ./bin/kafka-run-class kafka.tools.JmxTool --jmx-url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi --object-name kafka.server:type=app-info --attributes version
```

This will give you an ouput :

```
Trying to connect to JMX url: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi.
"time","kafka.server:type=app-info:version"
1556186760721,2.1.0-cp1
1556186762728,2.1.0-cp1
1556186764727,2.1.0-cp1
```

Note, that you should configure the property `--jmx-url` with your own environment info.

Comment: How do you get the `--jmx-url`?